# Applescript to make selection of channel in photoshop

Tags: applescript, photoshop

I need to make a selection of an alpha channel in a photoshop file. I have tried about everything I can think would work.

- Make selection of channel 4
- Create selection of channel 4 select
- channel 4 I have tried setting the current channel to channel 4 and then selecting all

I just can't get the selection. I am working with this tell block and just playing with the line after activate.

```
tell application id "com.adobe.Photoshop"
    tell current document
        activate
        create selection channel 4
    end tell
end tell
```

Note: Working in PS CC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application id "com.adobe.Photoshop"
    activate
    tell current document
        load selection of it from channel 4 of it
    end tell
end tell
```

(See page 46 of PS CC scripting guide)

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you, not sure how I missed it. Have some free points.